# How do you create a label inside actionPerformed after a click?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, scope, jlabel

How do you create a label after a click? (I have to create a label inside actionPerformed method, don't ask me why) ty !

```
 public static void main (String [] args)
 {
       JFrame Frame = new JFrame ();
       Frame.setSize(WIDTH_FRAME,HEIGHT_FRAME);
       Frame.setLayout(null);
       JButton Button = new JButton("x");
       Button.setBounds(a,b,c,d);
       Button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                                 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

             JLabel v = new JLabel ("xxxxxxxxxx");
            v.setBounds(50,50,50,50);
          Frame.add(v);
          Frame.revalidate();
          Frame.repaint();
          }
       });

       Frame.add(Button);
       Frame.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: *"..don't ask me why.."*  Why?  (And don't tell me/us what to do.)

Comment: Follow Java naming conventions. Variable names should NOT start with an upper case character.

Answer (score 2):

Do you understand the concept of scope? `JLabel v` is locally scoped and can't be accessed from outside the `actionPerformed`.  You can just put `Frame.add(v);` *inside* the `actionPerformed`. Then you need to `revalidate()` and `repaint()` the frame, as you should do when add components at runtime

---

**Side Notes**

- null layout cause many problem, so you should look into using layout managers. Take a look at [Laying out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) for more details.
- Swing apps should be run on the Event Dispatch Thread. You can do so by wrapping the code in the `main` in a `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(...)`. See more at [Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html)
- Note your hard coded values for `setBounds`. That will cause only one added label to be visible. I highly suggest looking into a layout managers like `FlowLayout` or `BoxLayout`. A layout that will make dynamically adding components more *"natural"*.

---

Example with Box Layout

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.Box;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class BoxLayoutDemo {

    private Box box;
    private int count = 1;
    public BoxLayoutDemo() {
        box = Box.createVerticalBox();
        JButton button = createButton();

        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(box);
        scroll.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 300));
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add(scroll);
        frame.add(button, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JButton createButton() {
        JButton button = new JButton("Add Label");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                box.add(new JLabel("JLabel " + count));
                box.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(10));
                box.revalidate();
                box.repaint();
                count++;
            }
        });
        return button;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            public void run() {
                new BoxLayoutDemo();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to call `Frame.revalidate(); Frame.repaint();` also when add components at runtime.

Comment: can you give me an example?

Comment: Why do you need example? I just told you what you need to do. `Frame.add(v); Frame.revalidate(); Frame.repaint();`

Comment: @MadProgrammer Seems to be the case.

Comment: I edited my code, can you check it? but how do I instantiate frame? just "JFrame Frame"?

Comment: `JFrame Frame` needs to be `final` since you're trying to access it from an annonymous inner class. `final JFrame Frame = new JFrame();`

Answer (score 2):

You don't seem to have a concept of an event driven environment and are thinking in a procedural manner...

This...

```
Button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        JLabel v = new JLabel ("xxxxxxxxxx");
        v.setBounds(50,50,50,50);
    }
});
```

Does not call the `actionPerformed` method when it's executed, there fore `v` is not created by the time you hit

```
Frame.add(v);  // this does not work
```

Despite the fact that `v` has a local content to the `actionPerformed` method and can't referenced externally.

`actionPerformed` will only be called if and when the `Button` is actioned in some pay (ie the user clicks on it).

Instead, you should do something more like...

```
Button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        JLabel v = new JLabel ("xxxxxxxxxx");
        v.setBounds(50,50,50,50);
        Frame.add(v);
    }
});
```

But now you have another problem, `Frame` only has local context to the `main` method.  You can rectify this by declaring `Frame` as `final`...

```
final JFrame Frame = new JFrame ();
```

**Notes:**

*Much of this iterates and supports peeskillet (+1) and is done because it's important and to round out the answer*

- Don't use `null` layouts.  Swing was designed to work with layout managers, you will have no end of issues getting the screen to update without them, besides, pixel perfect layouts are an illusion in modern user interface design, you don't control the fonts, rendering pipelines or other aspects of the target system that might effect how large elements like text are rendered.
- Read through and understand [Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html)
- Read through and use [Code Conventions for the Java Programming Language](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html)

Comment: I put final but when I click the button, nothing is showed. I also tried to remove       Frame.setLayout(null);, but the button became super big....

Comment: Try setting the layout manager to `FlowLayout` (`Frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout())`, add `Frame.revalidate()` and possibly `Frame.repaint()` after the label is added.